# how do I Install android on Alcatel one touch fire that runs firefox-os?

Tags: android, smartphone, firefox-os, rom, alcatel-ot

I have an Alcatel One Touch Fire, it runs Firefox OS. Actually the OS very buggy and the project is death. I'd like to install Android on it. how? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well Alcatel One Touch Fire is based on android like kernel but has only 256mbs of ram so even if u find a ROM that works with the phone u will still need to think about performance cause 256mb ram is good to run gingerbread which is outdated

Comment: Nah, it should be fine, there is a version of Alcatel One Touch with android using the exact same hardware. You only have to flash the android version of it.